# Attach Geospatial data to Image for Current Location without using Map provider

Tags: javascript, geospatial

I am looking to take an image and attach geobounds to it and provide a location dot or indicator over the image of where that user is in proximity to those bounds in Javascript. I could do calculations of current GPS coordinates in relation to the bounds and plot accordingly but would rather use a JS library to support this.

Thanks!

Comment: is this an image of a map? or a georeferenced image? or just a picture? do you know where the user is (from GPS?)?

Comment: It is an image of a building layout that has geo reference points at the corners of the building. The idea is that if the user is within the space, show their location using a dot over the image.